# onClick event from different xml layout view

Tags: android-layout, listview, buttonclick

in my TodoApp, i have two xml layout activity_main.xml and row.xml. as it can be seen that row.xml is for different use where i have taken Textview and button horizontally and i have given a onClick function(deleteTask) to the button in xml attribute in row.xml layout file and when i implement row.xml to my ArrayAdapter of ListView in MainActivity class it works fine but as i implemented the button onClick method of deleteTask of button view in MainActivity , Android Studio prompts me an error that "deleteTask is not found" can someone help help me how to handle onClick events of views from different layout, the layout which is not inflated in any class
Thanks in Advance

Comment: The button is on each row of the ListView, and you want to catch the click event on the Activity hosting the Listview?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same scenario